# Bootstrap v4 navbar , navbar-toggler-icon not working with react

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using bootstrap v4 with react and trying to use the navbar. Everything seems to be working just fine, but when the size of the page is small enough for the `navbar-toggler-icon` to show up and I click it, it does nothing. I will show the cdns I have and code as well.

EDIT: To prevent confusion or speculation that my code has somehow messed with the navbar, I have implemented in the default v4 navbar, which is still not working.

Nav component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      active: '1'
    };

    this.onActive = this.onActive.bind(this);
  }

  onActive(event, attr) {
    this.setState({
      active: attr
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Navbar
        </a>
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item active">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                Link
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                id="navbarDropdown"
                role="button"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  Action
                </a>
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  Another action
                </a>
                <div className="dropdown-divider" />
                <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  Something else here
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#">
                Disabled
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input
              className="form-control mr-sm-2"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
            <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
              Search
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>

    );
  }
}

const localStyles = {
  active: {
    backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3'
  }
};

export default Nav;
```

Index.mustache :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <!-- Turbo library imports: jQuery, Turbo CDN, sample app.js -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.turbo360-dev.com/dist/turbo.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle/commons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle/app.js"></script> <!-- React code bundle -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should it? You have no functionality implemented for your `span`

Comment: Aren't the bootstrap imports suppose to make it do that? In v3 I didn't have to add any special code for it.

Comment: Why do you use NULL in the className={`nav-item ${this.state.active === '4' ? 'active' : null}`}? Try leaving empty string, also, the state.active is an integer? because you are comparing the object type too.

Comment: I will try implementing in the default navbar see if what I did that affected it

Comment: @wrivas this did not fix it even with default navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how no one caught this or how I forgot, but you need to import jquery before bootstrap. So the new code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <!-- Turbo library imports: jQuery, Turbo CDN, sample app.js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.turbo360-dev.com/dist/turbo.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle/commons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle/app.js"></script> <!-- React code bundle -->
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the jquery is above the bootstrap import now.